# How to turn a column values into a list

Tags: apache-spark

I have dataset which i want to extract a column of values into a list, how to achieve that ?
I have tried :

```
List<Row> rows = dF.select("col1").collectAsList();
```

But then how to iterate over values of col1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a list of rows the same way you can iterate over any list.
For eg: Assuming you want to access the first column (string type) of all the rows, you can use the following snippet

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer
val  rows = df.select("col1").collectAsList();
rows.map(r => r.getAs[String](0))
```

Comment: in JAVA please !

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate over the list selected from a `column`, but it is not recommended if the column is big to fit in the driver node

```
df.select("col1").collectAsList()
    .stream().forEach(row -> System.out.println(row.getString(0)));
```

There are other functions for other datatype to get the value from `Row` like `getString`, `getLong`, `getInt` etc